# Read static property from object

Tags: swift

I have a class with a static property which I would like to access for a specific object. The code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

protocol Theme {
    static var name: String { get }

    func getBackgroundColor() -> UIColor
}

class DefaultTheme: Theme {
    static var name = "Default theme"

    func getBackgroundColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}

var currentTheme: Theme = DefaultTheme()
println(currentTheme.name) //Error: 'Theme' does not have a member named 'name'
```

I cannot acces the theme's name via `DefaultTheme.name` because `currentTheme` may be an instance of a different Theme class, but I do need to know it's name. How can I access this static variable?

I am using Xcode 6.3.1 (with Swift 1.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've hit an obscure and very interesting bug in Swift 1.2. Swift has a long history of bugs related to static variables required by protocols, and this appears to be another one.

The problem here, apparently, is that you have tried to mix and match protocol-based characteristics with class-based characteristics. Suppose you had said this:

```
var currentTheme = DefaultTheme()
```

Then `currentTheme` would be typed as a DefaultTheme - an instance of a class. This means you can access a class member from the instance by passing thru the `dynamicType` of that instance:

```
println(currentTheme.dynamicType.name) // "Default theme"
```

But you can't do that in *your* code, because you have typed `currentTheme` as a Theme - a protocol:

```
var currentTheme : Theme = DefaultTheme()
```

This does weird things to the notion of the `name` property, which is imposed by the protocol, and so you can't access the `name` property at all.

You would not have this problem if Theme were DefaultTheme's *superclass*. In that case, you could use a class property (which would have to be a computed property) and it would work polymorphically. In Swift 1.2, that might be your best bet:

```
class Theme {
    class var name : String { return "Theme" }
}
class DefaultTheme: Theme {
    override class var name : String { return "Default theme" }
}
var currentTheme : Theme = DefaultTheme()
println(currentTheme.dynamicType.name) // "Default theme"
```

On the other hand, when you upgrade to Swift 2, you will find that the bug is fixed, and so `print(currentTheme.dynamicType.name)` works perfectly even with a protocol:

```
protocol Theme {
    static var name : String { get }
}
class DefaultTheme: Theme {
    static var name = "Default theme"
}
var currentTheme : Theme = DefaultTheme()
print(currentTheme.dynamicType.name) // "Default theme"
```