# How to create generic convenience initializer in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm tackling with generics in Swift. I've got extension to `NSManagedObject` class and wanted to create initializer which is only available for classes which implements some protocol I defined. Now I've got something like below but this is not working and even not compiling. Could you help me make it working?

```
public extension NSManagedObject {
    public convenience init<Self: Nameable>(context: NSManagedObjectContext)     {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(Self.entityName(), inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }
}

public protocol Nameable {
    static func entityName() -> String
}
```

Xcode says: "Generic parameter 'Self' is not used in function signature".

Comment: Since you did not make anything adopt Nameable, it is unclear what you are even trying to do here. It seems to have no purpose. - Also, how is this generic to be resolved? - Also, Self has a meaning so you should not be misusing it as a placeholder name.

Comment: I've got other `NSManagedObject` subclasses and try to make them able to call `let obj = MyClass(context: context)`, but only if they implement `Nameable`. I see this is wrong declaration and should be more like this: `extension NSManagedObject where NSManagedObject: Nameable` but it also doesn't work this way.

Comment: But you cannot stop an instance from calling `let obj = MyClass(context:context)` on the basis of what class that instance is! That makes no sense at all, in any language. If there is an initializer `MyClass(context:context)`, _anyone_ can call it (if they can see it). That is the nature of object-oriented programming, if you see what I mean. Nor can I see any reason why you would _want_ to do that.

Comment: If you want to _inject_ a method into only classes that adopt a certain protocol, then what you want is a protocol extension (in Swift 2.0).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As matt already explained, you cannot define an initializer which
is restricted to types implementing a protocol. Alternatively, you
could define a global function instead:

```
public protocol Nameable {
    static func entityName() -> String
}

func createInstance<T : NSManagedObject>(type : T.Type, context : NSManagedObjectContext) -> T where T: Nameable {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: T.entityName(), in: context)!
    return T(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
}
```

which is then used as

```
let obj = createInstance(Entity.self, context)
```

You *can* avoid the additional type parameter if you define the method
as

```
func createInstance<T : NSManagedObject>(context : NSManagedObjectContext) -> T where T: Nameable { ... }
```

and use it as

```
let obj : Entity = createInstance(context)
```

or

```
let obj = createInstance(context) as Entity
```

where the type is now inferred from the context.

Comment: This seems like closest to what I wanted to have, but still, there is requirement to pass type in parameters of the method and I wanted to avoid this. As described in my answer I was wrong in my understanding of the problem ;) Thanks for this snippet anyway!

Comment: @TomaszSzulc: See update (but I am not sure which version is better)

Comment: I like the trick of making the placeholder the return type so as to avoid passing an instance of it as argument, as I do in my answer. I need to use that trick more often! :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are describing something like this:

```
class Thing {}

func makeANewThing<T:ThingMaker>(caller:T) -> Thing {
    let t = Thing()
    return t
}

protocol ThingMaker {
}

class Dog : ThingMaker {
}

class Cat { // not a ThingMaker
}

let t = makeANewThing(Dog()) // ok
let t2 = makeANewThing(Cat()) // illegal
```

In real life, I presume that `makeANewThing` would actually *do* something with its `caller`, but the point is that it can only be called by passing a `caller` that has adopted ThingMaker.

That is probably the best you can do in Swift 1. If you want to inject a method into only classes that adopt a certain protocol, then what you want is a protocol extension — but that is available only in Swift 2.

Comment: However, in your actual example, you are going to have further difficulties: you are going to be unable to retrieve the static `name` property of something typed as a Nameable, for reasons that I explain here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30824093/341994 Again, the solution is to upgrade to Swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for your comments on this thread. I realized with @matt comments that I cannot do what I thought because it is even not possible. I wanted to not create subclass to make it working and it was not possible with my understanding of the problem.

Finally I found another way to get entity name. It has pros and cons but I decided to use it for now. Then I created extension for `NSManagedObject` to make it work.

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    class func entityName() -> String {
        let fullClassName = NSStringFromClass(object_getClass(self))
        let nameComponents = split(fullClassName) { $0 == "." }
        return last(nameComponents)!
    }

    public convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let name = self.dynamicType.entityName()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(name, inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }
}
```

And then

```
obj = Obj(context: ctx)
```