# Difference between T and Self in generic methods

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

I’m writing a protocol called `JSONDataInitializable`, which will enable values to be initialized from `Data` that contains JSON using `JSONDecoder`.

Since [it’s not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30899432/7864562) to explicitly use generics within initializers, I declared a universal, type-agnostic helper method in a protocol extension, which the initializer later calls.

However, I came up with not one, but two ways to write such a method.

(1):

```swift
private static func initialize<T: JSONDataInitializable>(from jsonData: Data) throws -> T {
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
}
```

(2):

```swift
private static func initialize(from jsonData: Data) throws -> Self {
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: jsonData)
}
```

Could you explain the difference between these methods? They both seem to produce the same result.

The only visible difference is the protocol conformance part in the first variant. However, the methods are declared in a protocol extension and therefore only available to types which conform to the protocol.

**UPD**

Here’s the complete protocol declaration:

```swift
protocol JSONDataInitializable: Decodable {
    init?(from jsonData: Data)
}

extension JSONDataInitializable {

    init?(from jsonData: Data) {
        do {
            self = try Self.initialize(from: jsonData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }

    // (1)
    private static func initialize<T: JSONDataInitializable>(from jsonData: Data) throws -> T {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
    }

    // ⬆⬆⬆
    // OR
    // ⬇⬇⬇

    // (2)
    private static func initialize(from jsonData: Data) throws -> Self {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: jsonData)
    }

}
```

Let’s say we have a struct called `User` that’s `Decodable`. We need to initialize values of `User` from JSON (stored as `Data`). With the protocol, initialization works like that:

```swift
// Protocol conformance declaration
extension User: JSONDataInitializable { }

// JSON stored as Data
let networkData = ...

// Initialization
let john = User(from: networkData)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a custom protocol in your first method, simply restrict `T` to `Decodable`. Also, it would help if you included a [mcve], especially showing where (in what scope) these methods are declared.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks for your comment. I added the full protocol declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second implementation, using `Self` is the one that matches your requirements. You want to create an initializer in a protocol, which you can call on the type you want to initialize. `Self` in protocol functions refers to the type that you call the specific method on.

On the other hand, the generic implementation would allow you to initialize any types conforming to the protocol, but in your `init(from:)` method you assign the return value to `self`, so the generic type parameter `T` will be inferred as `Self`. This makes it unnecessary to make the method generic, since on a specific type, `T` will always be `Self`.